# ¿Cómo acceder al evento click de un boton en datatable dinamica JQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy trabajando con datatables Jquery dinamicamente, pero el evento para el click en el boton que se agrega a la tabla no está siendo llamado, estoy usando Jquery, Javascript, PHP.

```
//Esta es la definición de la tabla dinámica:
 $('#test_<?= $row['id'] ?>').dataTable({
     "aaData": jsonData,
      "searching": false,
       paging: false,
       info:false,
      "aoColumns": columns});

//creo el item para agregarlo al final de cada fila
  let lastItem = {
  "sTitle": "Action",
   "mData": null,
   "sDefaultContent": '<button type="button" name="btndelete"   id="btndelete" 
    class="btn fas fa-trash btndelete">'  
     };
 columns.push(lastItem);


//la documentación describe algo como esto, pero actualmente no esta haciendo lladama al evento:
 $('#test_<?= $row['id'] ?> tbody').on( 'click', 'button.btndelete', function () 
 {
    console.log("deleted")
 });

//código html de la tabla
 <table id="test_<?= $row['id']?>" class="table table-striped table-bordered 
   dt-responsive nowrap" style="width:100%">
</table>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes pegar también el código HTML que ocupas para tu tabla?

Comment: listo, ya lo agregué.

Comment: Hola. Tu problema se debe a que el nuevo botón ingresa al DOM; pero, el código que enlaza los eventos no se vuelve a ejecutar con cada cambio en el mismo. De modo que los observadores de evento no rastrean los nuevos elementos. La solución es **rebobinar**: crear un método en en que se enlazan los observadores y llamarlo cada vez que se agregan elementos al DOM, luego de insertarlos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta forma:

```
 $(document).on( 'click', '#test_<?= $row['id'] ?> tbody', function (){
    console.log("deleted")
 });
```